# How to get count for last two months with their difference in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

### How to get count for last two months with their difference.

Suppose: I have records for the past two years

input:

```
Date           |    sales   
01-JAn- 2019   |    25
29-jan- 2019   |    90
30-Jan-2019    |    45
25-Feb- 2019   |    78
26_feb_2019    |    40
-------------------------------------------------------------
```

Ouput

```
Date          |      Count      |    %Difference

JAN           |    160          |   42 (%Difference)

Feb           |    118          |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to want:

```
select to_char(date, 'YYYY-MM'), sum(count),
       (sum(count) - lag(sum(count)) over (partition by min(date)) as difference
from t
group by to_char(date, 'YYYY-MM')
order by min(date) desc
fetch first 2 rows only;
```

Note, this will include a difference for the second month, if there is more historical data.  This seems like a "feature".  But you can address this by aggregating and then filtering using a `where` clause:

```
select yyyymm,
       (cnt - lag(cnt) over (partition by yyyymm) as difference
from (select to_char(date, 'YYYY-MM') as yyyymm, sum(count) as cnt,
             row_number() over (order by min(date) desc) as seqnum
      from t
      group by to_char(date, 'YYYY-MM')
     ) yc
where sequm <= 2
order by yyyymm desc
```